# i heve an error in flutter app when i am using velocity x in my flutter project

Tags: flutter

I have an error in the flutter app when I am using velocity x in my flutter project.

Error:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#b1110 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///C:/Users/lokesh%20jangid/AndroidStudioProjects/lokeshjangid/lib/main.dart:13:12
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: velocity x is a package of flutter. it is used for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error but I know this is due to the wrong alignment of widgets. This can also happen even without velocity X if widgets are not aligned correctly.